# JavaFX scene freezes when second Button is clicked

Tags: java, fxml, apache-commons

I have a FXML JavaFX Scene with three buttons.

Button 1: Telnet, enter command1 + output Telnet session in TextArea of the JavaFX scene.

Button 2: Telnet, enter command2 + output Telnet session in TextArea of the JavaFX scene.

Button 3: Telnet, enter command3 + output Telnet session in TextArea of the JavaFX scene.

The problem is that after clicking a button, the JavaFX scene freezes when I click a second button.

I've already redirected the output of the Telnet session to the console, but this has the same result.
This is the last output in the console:

**(110)oxea> #ý**

**(110)oxea>**  is the prompt, it is the **#ý** that are apparently the last characters sent.

If I remove the Telnet action from a button, then it is no problem to click this button after I clicked another with a Telnet action.

If I compile the program the same problem occurs.

I've also tried following: after compiling, I ranthe program two times simultaneously, and as I expected: after I click on a button in the first program, the second program immediatley freezes when clicking a button.

There are no Exeptions thrown, and I can't find any topics which describe and fix this problem.

FXMLController:

```
@FXML private Text buttonPressed;
@FXML private Button button1;
@FXML private Button button2;
@FXML public TextArea actionConsole;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    button1.setOnAction((event) -> {
        buttonPressed.setText("");
        buttonPressed.setText("button1 pressed");
        actionConsole.clear();

        TelnetSRV t1 = new TelnetSRV("0.0.0.0", "user", "password", "ls -l");
    });

    button2.setOnAction((event) -> {
        buttonPressed.setText("");
        buttonPressed.setText("button1 pressed");
        actionConsole.clear();
        TelnetSRV t2 = new TelnetSRV("0.0.0.0", "user", "password", "df -h");
```

So, when clicking on a button, a text is displayed, the TextArea actionConsoel is cleared, and the TelnetSRV is performed. This works on the first click, but on the second click the program freezes.

The error is almost certainly to be found in the TelnetSRV class, because when running another class whith two TelnetSRV's, this also freezes after the first TelnetSRV.

TelnetSRV:

```
public class TelnetSRV  {
    private TelnetClient tc = new TelnetClient();
    private InputStream in;
    private PrintStream out;
    private String prompt = "(110)oxea>";

    public TelnetSRV(String server, String user, String password, String command) {
        try {
            tc.connect(server, 23);
            in = tc.getInputStream();
            out = new PrintStream(tc.getOutputStream());

            readUntil("login: ");
            write(user);
            readUntil("Password: ");
            write(user);
            readUntil(prompt + " ");
            write(command);
            readUntil(prompt + " ");
            tc.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String readUntil(String pattern) {
        try {
            char lastChar = pattern.charAt(pattern.length() - 1);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            boolean found = false;
            char ch = (char) in.read();
            while (true) {
                System.out.print(ch);
                sb.append(ch);
                if (ch == lastChar) {
                    if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) {
                       return sb.toString();
                    }
                }
                ch = (char) in.read();
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    public void write(String value) {
        try {
            out.println(value);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are never able to connect to the server and that is causing your UI to freeze. Perhaps you could set a timeout and run your connection in a separate thread from the UI.

Comment: Hello,
I am able to connect, I can see the output of the first Telnet session. The second Telnet session is to the same server (same user, same password).

Comment: I'm going to take a tcpdump to see is the second session even tries to connect.

Comment: It seems that the second telnet session begins, but the data sent from the application to the server is not complete.

Hex dump Session 1 (application to server)

00000000  ff fb 18                                           ...

00000003  ff fc 20 ff fc 23 ff fc  27                  .. ..#.. '

0000000C  ff fa 18 00 56 54 31 30  30 ff f0    ....VT10 0..

                    Hex dump Session 2 (application to server)
00000000  ff fb 18        ...

00000003  ff fc 23        ..#

This is all data that is sent by the application

The 2nd session stops immediately after connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Telnet trace gave me the idea that my code was ok, so I started searching for bug reports on the TelnetClient.

I then found out the problem was caused by the Apache common-net library I used.

**I replaced commons-net-3.0.1 with commons-net-3.6**, and now the two telnet sessions run without any problems.

Thank you

Comment: Please accept your own answer so others can tell the problem has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought you could do it sooner :)